Raycast - Why are the ray intersections not at the right location?
I have an ellipsoid and a conical frustum.
The ellipsoid is centred at cellipsoid, and the small-radius frustum base at cfrustum.
The frustum is such that its main axis is directed in the line-of-sight vector between cellipsoid and cfrustum.
The length of the frustum is that of the line-of-sight vector.
I want to get the intersection coordinates between the frustum and the ellipsoid.
To do so, I have two functions identifying the vertices belonging to the small-radius and big-radius frustum bases
import numpy as np
import mathutils
import bpy

def get_vertices_coords_base(frustum,cfrustum,r1):
    """
    Function returning the position vector of the vertices belonging to the small-radius conical frustum base

    Parameters
    ----------
    frustum : bpy.types.Object
        Blender object representing the conical frustum mesh
    cfrustum : mathutils.Vector
        Small-radius conical base centre position vector
    r1 : float
        Small-base radius

    Returns
    -------
    base_vertices : list[mathutils.Vector]
        List of position vectors of vertices belonging to the small-radius conical frustum base
    """
    # Get the vertices in world space
    base_vertices = []
    tol = 1.0e-3
    for vert in frustum.data.vertices:
        world_co = frustum.matrix_world @ vert.co
        if np.abs((world_co - cfrustum).length - r1) <= tol:
            base_vertices.append(world_co)

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    return base_vertices

def get_vertices_coords_top(frustum,cfrustum,r2):
    """
    Function returning the position vector of the vertices belonging to the big-radius conical frustum base

    Parameters
    ----------
    frustum : bpy.types.Object
        Blender object representing the conical frustum mesh
    cfrustum : mathutils.Vector
        Big-radius conical base centre position vector
    r2 : float
        Big-base radius

    Returns
    -------
    top_vertices : list[mathutils.Vector]
        List of position vectors of vertices belonging to the big-radius conical frustum base
    """
    top_vertices = []
    tol = 1.0e-3
    for vert in frustum.data.vertices:
        world_co = frustum.matrix_world @ vert.co
        if np.abs((world_co - cfrustum).length - r2) <= tol:
            top_vertices.append(world_co)

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    return top_vertices

These functions allow me to get the top and bottom vertices
base_points = get_vertices_coords_hel_base(frustum = frustum, cfrustum = cfrustum, r1 = r1)
top_points = get_vertices_coords_hel_top(frustum = frustum, cfrustum = cellipsoid, r2 = r2)

I then have methods to compute a ray orientation and to draw it
def calculate_ray_direction(start,end):
    relative_vec = end - start
    length = relative_vec.length
    direction = relative_vec.normalized()
    angle = np.arctan2(base_radius, length)
    rotation_axis = direction.cross(mathutils.Vector((0, 0, 1))).normalized()
    rotation_quat = mathutils.Quaternion(rotation_axis, angle)
    return rotation_quat @ direction

def draw_ray(start,end,collection):
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name = "Ray")
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name = "Ray", object_data = mesh)
    collection.objects.link(obj)

    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.verts.new(start)
    bm.verts.new(end)
    bm.edges.new(bm.verts)
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)
    bm.free()

I then create the rays linking the top and bottom vertices of the frustum mesh and store the locations of the corresponding intersection coordinates
intersec_vertices = []
for start, end in zip(base_points, top_points):
    ray_direction = calculate_ray_direction(start = start, end = end)
    hit, loc, norm, idx = ell.ray_cast(origin = start,direction = ray_direction)
    draw_ray(start, end, ray_collection)
    intersec_vertices.append(loc)

The coordinates stored in intersec_vertices are not correct, and I do not get why?

Dawg just use descriptive variable names for pete's sake, All the "typing" you saved by cutting each variable name to some cryptic code sure went out the window the moment you had to explain your code to literally anyone else. Lmao. :D

@Jakemoyo I changed the variable names. Hopefully it is clearer now
